# Git post-receive not working

Tags: git

I am new to git. I have created a bare git repo on the server. I have a local git repo in my system. After commit, before pushing to the main repo, i push to server repo. In server repo, the following code is added to the hooks/post-receive
`date >> /home/d.txt` 
when i try to run the script by ssh into the server using `sh post-receive`,the script runs fine. But when i do a local git push, the script is not running. ie the date is not inserted.
The permission settings of post-receive is `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`
**Update:**
I inserted the code `echo "uploading"` in the hooks/post-receive file and changed the permissions by executing `chmod +x hooks/post-receive` of my local git. When i do a local git push, the post-receive file is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be called `post-receive` ... i.e. drop the .sh suffix.

Comment: oops! i added .sh in my question by mistake. I have made the correction in the question. Actually i have named it post-receive only and when i run `sh post-receive` the script is running. But the script is not triggering when done a local git push.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your post-receive script is in the server's .git/hooks, not in the client's one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure is that the owner of the post-receive script is user **git**. And also check the script under the **git** account, may be git user not have permission for write to **/home/d.txt**